# Liferay Date picker using alloy ui

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I am having problems tring to use a alloy ui  datepiker in liferay.

my code:

```
<%

Campagna campagna = (Campagna) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.CAMPAGNA);

long campagnaId = 0;

if (campagna != null) {
    campagnaId = campagna.getCampagnaId();
}

//campagna.getDate()

%>
    <input type="text" name="dataFine" id="<portlet:namespace />dataFine" size="30"  />

    <aui:script>

        AUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(A) {

           var dataInizioDatepicker = new A.DatePicker({

             trigger: '#<portlet:namespace />dataInizio',
               calendar: {
                dateFormat: '%d/%m/%y'
                }


           }).render('##<portlet:namespace />dataInizioPicker');



        });

    </aui:script>
```

What I am tring to do is set the campagna.getDate() value to the datepiker, but I can't find a way.

The second problem is the date format.

I want the the date format of the datepiket is based on the current language of liferay.

There is a way to do this?

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'dates' attribute for setting date

```
        AUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(A) {
           var dataInizioDatepicker = new A.DatePicker({
             trigger: '#<portlet:namespace />dataInizio',
                  calendar: {
                     dates: [ '${campagna.date}' ],
                dateFormat: '%m/%d/%Y'
             }
           }).render('##<portlet:namespace />dataInizioPicker');
```

Comment: It will work. In jsp, when your script is executed, EL will convert java date into value for dates[]. Try it and let me know if its not working